# StringBuilder, add Tab between Values

Tags: c#, string, tabs, append, stringbuilder

I have a small problem:

I have a List of fields, with 3 Values. I want to build my String with these three Values,
delimited by a **"TAB"**..

Code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(field).Append("\t");
}
stringBuilder.AppendLine();
return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The Tab is only between the 3rd and 2nd Value (Between 1st and 2nd is a Space ?!)

So I tried this:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(field + "\t").Append("\t");
}
stringBuilder.AppendLine();
return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Then I have 2 Tabs between 3rd and 2nd, one Tab between 1st and 2nd and also a Space
between 1st and 2nd..

(The Space is always there, how to avoid that?)

So what I have to do? Need **only** (without spaces..) a Tab between these Values..

Comment: How do you verify the tab is not there? By looking at where on the screen the text ends up?

Comment: At least I'm taking the String (return) and I copy it to Clipboard via Code, then I paste it in the Notepad

Comment: Are you aware that Notepad sets tab stops at fixed points, and if your tab ends up close to such point, it will appear as narrow as a space?

Comment: just saw that now.. Tried it then in Word and there it works.. Well Problem solved ;D

Comment: probably could do with looking in notepad++/vim or something with a binary editor to look at what you actually have

Comment: should download it first hehe

Comment: hmm, notepad++ shows the same like notepad, the false things, but Word shows it well...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(field.Trim()).Append("\t");
}
stringBuilder.AppendLine();
return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Basically I would just use [`return string.Join ( "\t", fields );`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) .

Comment: just solved the problem, look at Question Comment, but the Idea with Trim is good, I'l mark that as answer :)

Comment: Is this platform independent ? for example, Environment.Newline is platform independent while "\n" is not.

Comment: @blasto AFAIK there is only one character for "Tab" - so IMHO this is platform-independent...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing with tab char and sapces.

Are you expecting fixed no of white spaces to be added in the end of every word?

\t -> is just a tab char

The following is generated by the code given by you.

```
Java    StackOverflow   Banyan
Javasun StackOverflow   Banyan
```

The above two lines have same tab char b/w the 1st & 2nd Word.

if you type one more char in the end of "Javasun" it will extend like the following

```
Javaasunk   StackOverflow   Banyan
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you would want

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(field);
    stringBuilder.Append("\t");
}
stringBuilder.AppendLine();
return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: although looking at MSDN, Append returns a reference to the stringbuilder anyway so shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: it's the same.. but just solved the problem, look at Question Comment

Comment: yep, I added a comment up there too

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, you can use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx):

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.AppendLine(string.Join("\t", fields));
```

Note that you can pass in the string directly to `AppendLine` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub WarningWindow(ByVal content As String)
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace("""", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim a As String = "Welcomeback"
    'GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1400,height=500,resize=yes,scrollbars =yes');")
    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
    sb.Append("<INPUT Type=Button Name=Close Size=40  Value='Clsose(GSS)' onclick='self.close()'; / > ")
    sb.Append("</br><INPUT Type=Button Name=fu Size=40  Value='Alert' onclick=javascript:window.alert('" & a & "'); / > ")
    sb.Append("<INPUT Type=Text Name=gss Size=40  Value=300 ; / > ")
    sb.Append(" <P>")
    sb.Append(content)
    sb.Append(""");")
    sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
    sb.Append("printWin.show;};")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "suvesh", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: call it like WarningWindow("write any thing")